# Since I update my Symfony2 project. Each fields became "required"

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-2.1

I found a little solution to my problem. It's to put a `'required' => false`, in the field of the formType. But before, it was working without that... so I ask. If there is a problem or it's normal?

Yesterday, I upgrated my Sf2.1 project with `composer.phar`

```
$ php ../composer.phar update
```

Now I'm using this composer.json

```js
{
    // ...
    "require": {
        "symfony/symfony": "2.1.*",
        // ...
    },
    "scripts": {
        // ...
    },
    "config": {
        "bin-dir": "bin"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "extra": {
        "symfony-app-dir": "app",
        "symfony-web-dir": "web"
    },
    "repositories": [
        // ...
    ]
}
```

For example in my Entity File:

```php
/**
 * @var date $deliveryDate
 * 
 * @ORM\Column(name="deliveryDate", type="date", nullable=true)
 */
private $deliveryDate;
```

Then in my FormType

```php
        ->add('deliveryDate', 'date', array(
            'widget' => 'single_text',
            'label' => 'Date de livraison',
            'input' => 'datetime',
( solution: 'required' => false, )
            'format' => 'dd/MM/yyyy',
            'attr' => array('class' => 'datepicker'),
         ))
```

As you understood, the problem isn't in the Database part but, in the FormPart.

Comment: Seems pretty normal. Happens to me all the time. I always have to manually set required as false so it doesn't trigger the html5 required function.

Answer (score 0):

Symfony 2.1 invokes the HTML5 required functionality by default. You'll have to set required to false on every field you want to be optional.